# Create Array of Objects Based on 2 Arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array, it looks like this.

```
const date = ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05']
```

I have an array of objects, it looks like this.

```
const data = [
  {
    category: 'a',
    date: '2021-01-01',
    qty: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'a',
    date: '2021-01-02',
    qty: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'b',
    date: '2021-01-02',
    qty: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'b',
    date: '2021-01-03',
    qty: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'c',
    date: '2021-01-03',
    qty: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'c',
    date: '2021-01-04',
    qty: '2'
  },
]
```

I want the result to be like this, the datasets's length should be 5 (based on date's length).

```
[
  {
    label: 'a',
    datasets: ['1', '2', '0', '0', '0']
  },
  {
    label: 'b',
    datasets: ['0', '1', '2', '0', '0']
  },
  {
    label: 'c',
    datasets: ['0', '0', '1', '2', '0']
  },
]
```

I tried code by myself, but the result looks like this

```
[
  {
    label: 'a',
    datasets: ['1', '2']
  },
  {
    label: 'b',
    datasets: ['1', '2']
  },
  {
    label: 'c',
    datasets: ['1', '2']
  },
]
```

Can anyone help me to code this?

**Edit**

```js
const data = [
  {
    category: 'a',
    date: '2021-01-01',
    qty: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'a',
    date: '2021-01-02',
    qty: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'b',
    date: '2021-01-02',
    qty: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'b',
    date: '2021-01-03',
    qty: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'c',
    date: '2021-01-03',
    qty: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'c',
    date: '2021-01-04',
    qty: '2'
  },
];
var output = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
  var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
    return v.label == item.category;
  });
  if (existing.length) {
    var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
    output[existingIndex].datasets = output[existingIndex].datasets.concat(item.qty);
  } else {
    if (typeof item.qty == 'string') item.qty = [item.qty];
    output.push({
      label: item.category,
      datasets: item.qty
    });
  }
});
console.log('Output', output);
```

Comment: Plz share your code till now

Comment: This is my current code on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yfbnpL10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, you do not respect the lenth of the dat array and just `push` the value to the `datasets` of the group.

To overcome this, you could take an object for getting the index of the date and for not given `datasets`, map `date` with value zero.

```js
const
    dates = ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    data = [{ category: 'a', date: '2021-01-01', qty: '1' }, { category: 'a', date: '2021-01-02', qty: '2' }, { category: 'b', date: '2021-01-02', qty: '1' }, { category: 'b', date: '2021-01-03', qty: '2' }, { category: 'c', date: '2021-01-03', qty: '1' }, { category: 'c', date: '2021-01-04', qty: '2' }],
    indices = Object.fromEntries(dates.map((k, i) => [k, i])),
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((groups, { category: label, date, qty }) => {
        groups[label] ??= { label, datasets: Array.from(dates).fill('0') };
        groups[label].datasets[indices[date]] = qty;
        return groups;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great solution. Nice detail about the `.as-console-wrapper` CSS rule for the code snippet output. May I ask how you learned about this CSS class? I didn't know about it before and the only reference I could find so far was [this post on StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342321/4174789).

Comment: @BartHofland,  i copied it just from another answer here with javascript tag.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Thank you. :)